# passing for loop index into awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to pass a for loop index i into awk but keep getting unexpected token awk errors.

First I tried using the -v option within awk:

```
for i in "${myarray}"
awk -v var=$i '/var/{print}' myfile.dat
done
```

I also tried calling the variable directly using single quotes:

```
for i in "${myarray}"
awk '/'"$i"'/{print}' myfile.dat
done
```

My end goal is to learn how to pass a for loop index variable through awk as the search pattern. I'd like the above code to search through `myfile.dat` and print lines which contain the strings in `myarray`.

Comment: Be aware that you almost certainly neither want nor need a shell loop: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. Array traversing should be like this `for i in "${myarray[@]}"`
2. `awk` treats text between `/.../` as regex literal, to use a variable use `$0 ~ var`.

Your code should be:

```
for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
   awk -v var="$i" '$0 ~ var' myfile.dat
done
```

`{print}` is default action in `awk` that you can omit as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same loop free as well, e.g.,

```
echo "${myarray[@]}" | tr ' ' '|' | awk 'NR==FNR{pat=$0; next} $0 ~ pat' - file
```